# Why does setEditing:animated: and insertRowsAtIndexPaths: result in this weird editing style animation?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a `UITableView` on which I'm toggling `setEditing:animated:` on, to allow the user to insert and delete rows. When editing is turned on, I want a new `insert new item` row to be added to the table and then I want the editing controls to animate in like normal. I don't want the new `insert new item` row to animate in on its own, using something like a fade. I want it to just appear, and then slide in like any existing table data source rows do.

Here's what is happening as a result of my current code, though (click for larger view):

[image]

The top row does what I want - it simply slides over and the delete icon fades in. When it disappears, the delete icon fades out and the row expands again.

The second row is my non-data-source row that I add to the table myself. On appearing, it does not animate in at all. The insert icon and row appear all at once and do not slide in. When it disappear, the row expands nicely, but the plus icon slides with it. The animation is occurring for the entire row, and not for the plus icon and then row separately, like the first row.

Here's a quick run-down of my code, but I think providing a link to the class file might be better.

When an edit button on my toolbar is pressed, I call my `UIViewController` method `setEditing:animated:`. In this method, I do the following ...

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // keep the table in the same editing mode
    [_table setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {

        [_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_channels.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    } else {

        [_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_channels.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    }

}
```

This is where the animations of the inserting is occuring. I've tried wrapping the whole thing in [_table beginUpdate] and endUpdate, as well as just the row insertion. Neither seems to produce the clean animation I'm aiming for.

Any ideas what I might be missing? The whole code file is here:

https://github.com/ryancole/pound-client/blob/master/pound-client/controllers/ChannelListViewController.m#L106-L127

Comment: Is this too localized? I know there's a way to keep these animations in sync, because I see other apps do it.

Comment: try to move [super setEditing:editing animated:animated]; at the end of your setEditing method

Comment: +1 for the animated gif!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The super call does the sliding 'to editing' animation so if you insert something after it, it won't take part in it. What you want to do is insert the row before that call and remove the row after. You'll also need to keep track of the rows with a different boolean.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    _amEditing = editing;

    if (editing) {

        [_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_channels.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    } 

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // keep the table in the same editing mode
    [self.view setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (!editing)
    {
        [_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_channels.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }


}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _amEditing ? _channels.count + 1 : _channels.count;
}
```

UPDATE:

The second to last row's icon still has a strange animation.. to work around this you can add a delay to the deletion..

```
    if (!editing)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(deleteLastRow) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
    }

-(void) deleteLastRow
{
    [self.view deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_objects.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this is very close! The table cells are animating properly now, and in unison. For some reason though, the edit identifiers (the add and delete circles) are not animating the same. When entering editing mode, they both animate in properly, but when leaving editing mode, the delete circle sort of just fades out (which I think is the intended animation) while the add circle animates out by sliding back out left off screen as if it's performing the same animation as the cell. Looks like the fix would be an adjustment to when the various `setEditing` functions are called. Any ideas?

Comment: To add more details, the edit icons animate the same way as in my original animated GIF, when leaving editing mode. The table row cells are animating properly, though.

Comment: I have marked this as the answer, since the animation seems to tangentially related and not directly due to the cells animating. I can't award the bounty for another 5 hours, though. In the mean time, I'll go post about this on some forums or something.

Comment: Played around with this some more.. seems to have the desired behavior with a delayed selector.

Comment: I just got around to trying this work-around out, and it's not going to work. If you press the edit/done button really fast, it'll crash. I'd have to also add in some state to disable the button while it's animating. There has to be something I'm doing incorrectly or something. :/

Comment: Yea I guess if you want to protect against someone mashing the button, then yea i would disable it. I don't think you are doing anything wrong.. that animation is a strange behavior, it seems like a last minute patch apple threw on for deleting a row right after finishEditing

Answer (score 1):

As is commented you have to call `[super setEditing:editing animated:animated]` after you insert the row

```
 - (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

    // remove this [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    // keep the table in the same editing mode
    [_table setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {

        [_table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_channels.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    } else {

        [_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:_channels.count inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    }
  [super setEditing:editing animated:animated]; // add it here

}
```